# Reopen Web Part once closed in Web Part Maintenance Page

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-server, web-part-page

I've got an error happening on a page, so I closed all the web parts on it with the Web Part Maintenance Page. This indeed made the issue go away.

Trouble is, how do I reopen the web parts so that I can find out which web part is causing the issue? The only options i see are to Close or Delete. Reset does not open them back up; I'm not sure what it does to be honest.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot open that web part from "Web Part Maintenance Page" again. Instead you have to "Edit Page". Then click "Add web part". From left pane, in the categories click "Closed Web Parts", and then select your closed web part to be restored.

Comment: thanks, never would have found that! Very strange way of doing things...

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked for me. Some how, I closed a webpart of my sharepoint site in my office without permission. It had all the critical information of other team as well. I was too much worried. and this article saved my life. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much guys its really worked for me...! Thanks specially to paiman

Answer (score 0):

One follow up note.  One of my users deleted a part from his view of the page - the rest of us could still see it.  On the Web Part maintenance page there were now 2 instances of the part listed - one open, one closed.  Following the above suggestion to add the Closed part would work but would create 2 instances of the part for those of us who hadn't lost it in the first place.  In this case, I just deleted the part for everyone and re-added it to the page.  Problem solved.